# Create an ASCII table from CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, formatting, ascii-art

The following code convert csv to ascii table.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import argparse
import logging
import prettytable
import csv

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("infile", nargs="?", type=argparse.FileType("r"), default=sys.stdin)
parser.add_argument(
    '-d',
    '--debug',
    help="Print lots of debugging statements",
    action="store_const",
    dest="loglevel",
    const=logging.DEBUG,
    default=logging.WARNING,
)
parser.add_argument(
    '-v',
    '--verbose',
    help="Be verbose",
    action="store_const",
    dest="loglevel",
    const=logging.INFO,
)
args = parser.parse_args()

# taking input from stdin which is empty, so there is neither a stdin nor a file as argument
if sys.stdin.isatty() and args.infile.name == "<stdin>":
    sys.exit("Please give some input")

logging.basicConfig(level=args.loglevel)

# # Business Logic Here

table = None

content = csv.reader(args.infile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

for row in content:
    if table is None:
        table = prettytable.PrettyTable(row)
    else:
        table.add_row(row)

print(table)
```

Please let me know how I can make this code better.

Comment: You don't need a csv to print an ASCII table, Python has a builtin function that returns the character located the Unicode codepoint for any inputted integer in the range [0, 1114111]: `chr`. ASCII is codepoints [0, 255], in Python: `range(256)`. Use a list comprehension to get the characters: `[chr(i) for i in range(256)]`.  If you want a square: `[[chr(16*i+j) for j in range(16)] for i in range(16)]`

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς This sounds interesting. can you please elaborate in the answer section. I could not completely understand what you are saying.

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς, I think you have misunderstood what the code does (admittedly the description is very brief).  It seems to be about _formatting_ an existing table using ASCII formatting (`-`, `|` and `+`), rather than making a table _of_ the ASCII characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand the point of this test:

> ```
> if sys.stdin.isatty() and args.infile.name == "<stdin>":
>     sys.exit("Please give some input")
> ```

We want to disallow a particular file name, but only if we're connected to a tty?  If you want to prompt when input is coming from stdin, then we shouldn't be testing the file *name*, but instead its properties.  And I don't see why we should exit in this case (e.g. we might want to type directly, or copy-paste input).  I suggest:

```
if args.infile.isatty():
    print("Please enter your data:")
```

We might want to add a hint such as `Finish with control-D` - I'll leave it as an exercise to discover the terminal's control bindings and print the correct keystroke.

---

We don't need to read one row at a time.  `prettytable` can do that for us:

```
table = prettytable.from_csv(args.infile)
```

However, it requires the stream to be seekable, so if it's not, we'll need to read it into memory and pass that as a stream:

```
if not args.infile.seekable():
    from io import StringIO
    args.infile = StringIO(args.infile.read())

table = prettytable.from_csv(args.infile)
```

---

It's probably a good idea to print only the message from any exceptions, rather than an entire backtrace (unless the user asks for the extra detail):

```
try:
    if not args.infile.seekable():
        from io import StringIO
        args.infile = StringIO(args.infile.read())
    print(prettytable.from_csv(args.infile))
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(e, exc_info=(args.loglevel<=logging.DEBUG))
    exit(1)
```

---

## Modified code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import argparse
import logging
import prettytable
import csv

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "infile", nargs="?",
    type=argparse.FileType("r"),
    default=sys.stdin
)
parser.add_argument(
    '-d', '--debug',
    help="Print lots of debugging statements",
    action="store_const", dest="loglevel", const=logging.DEBUG,
    default=logging.WARNING,
)
parser.add_argument(
    '-v', '--verbose',
    help="Be verbose",
    action="store_const", dest="loglevel", const=logging.INFO,
)
args = parser.parse_args()

logging.basicConfig(level=args.loglevel)

if args.infile.isatty():
    print("Please enter your data:")

try:
    if not args.infile.seekable():
        from io import StringIO
        args.infile = StringIO(args.infile.read())

    table = prettytable.from_csv(args.infile)
    print(table)
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(e, exc_info=(args.loglevel<=logging.INFO))
    exit(1)
```

Comment: There is a comment above the line which i know is sort of incomprehensible. We can take input from either file (0) or stdin(1). So there are four combinations. 00, 01, 10, 11. The lines you mentioned deal with 00.

Comment: We take input from a File object, i.e. a stream, which could be connected to a terminal, a seekable file,  a named pipe, etc.  Your version fails if we attempt to read a file called `<stdin>` - e.g. `python3 273995.py '<stdin>'` refuses.  On the other hand `python3 273995.py /dev/tty` doesn't issue the prompt where my version does.  Do you have an example where your version does better than mine?

Comment: I replaced everything bellow `# # Business Logic Here` with `table = prettytable.from_csv(args.infile)` and printed the table. It just works.

Comment: I had meant to show the resultant modified program; I've now added it to the answer for convenience.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code.

Answer (score 3):

A few things that I would change:

1. Use functions - move some of the logic to functions; this change will enable you to reuse your code more easily in the future. It will also make unit testing much easier.
2. `sys.exit()` will only print the error to standard error stream. It's preferable to use the `logging` package instead.
3. Handle and communicating errors better - maybe the CSV is corrupted? Maybe it's empty and then you will print "None" to the user who will not understand what is the problem, so add more checks, log on error and better communicate the errors to the user.

Comment: Can you please add code to your answer.

Comment: Note that demonstrative code isn't _required_ in an answer.  If a review includes suggested alternatives, that can sometimes make it more helpful, but it's not always appropriate.